# Offline Bing Map control default tile image when no tile source at zoom level

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps

Very quick feeler for ideas or methods for implementing a default "no data at this level" tile layer for my bing maps control.  Currently when the zoom level or area i am looking at has no data the control is simply white.

I would like to show a no data at this level repeating image.

Any ideas welcomed.

Comment: A quick hack way of putting a background on empty tiles is to use map cruncher to overlay a solid colour png over the whole world at zoom level 1, and use this single layer as the base layer, this will give a coloured or patterned background.  not quite the answer i wanted but will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Bing Maps control, other than the WP8/8.1 controls, offline is against the terms of use of Bing Maps.